# NSDateFormatter is returning null for date in ios 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I am converting string to date and again to string. using following code

```
 NSString *newDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Jobs *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]Date]];


    NSLog(@"New Date is %@",newDate);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:newDate];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];

    NSLog(@"DAte is %@",str);
```

It is returning date in simulator but not in iphone 4.3.3
please help

Comment: Yes .. I am having label in UITableviewcell

Comment: [cell setJobDate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` will return nil if it can't get the date from a string.
To see if it can parse the date add an other NSLog statement:

```
NSString *newDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Jobs *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]Date]];

NSLog(@"New Date is %@",newDate);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *myDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:newDate];
NSLog(@"Date parsed: %@", myDate);

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];

NSLog(@"DAte is %@",str);
```

But since you only want the firs part of the string why not just substring it.

```
NSString *str = [newDate substringToIndex:10];
```

and what is returned here:

```
NSString *newDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Jobs *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]Date]];
```

it the property Date already a NSDate ?, can you show your .h file for Jobs?

Comment: New Date is 7/14/2011 3:49:34 AM this is coming from webservice I want to remove time from this..

Comment: This is proper in device. but after conversion it is returning null

Comment: 2011-09-12 16:32:40.612 ITClassifiedUniversal[2802:607] New Date is 6/2/2011 7:12:32 AM
2011-09-12 16:32:40.617 ITClassifiedUniversal[2802:607] Date parsed: (null)
2011-09-12 16:32:40.618 ITClassifiedUniversal[2802:607] DAte is (null)

Comment: You see that the date parsed is null, because your format string isn't correct.

Comment: But it is only for device..  what should I do