# NSDateFormatter IOS Bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i have a function to convert into `NSDate` by using `NSDateFormatter`.

```
+(NSDate*)getDateFromCurrentTimestamp:(NSString*)currentTimestamp{
//    currentTimestamp= @"28-Feb-2012 16:42:19 PM";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:NO];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    //[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentTimestamp];
}
```

IOS 5.x is returned correct `NSDate`.
when run on 4.1 & 4.2 also returned correct `NSDate`. 
when run on 4.3.2 & 4.3.3, it's returned `null`.

how is it possible? any workaround of this?

---

**EDIT**

This is **not** caused by iOS bug. this is related to phone itself. some phone has different `locale` set in device. so we had to force it to use one `locale`.

Comment: Are your `region` and `locale` set for the 4.3.2 & 4.3.3 devices? See if [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559182/how-do-you-interpret-dates-with-nsdateformatter/1559284#1559284) helps

Comment: Yeah, you probably correct. maybe the issue is related to `locale` not ios version. I'll try in a bit.

Comment: It worked with: `[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] autorelease]];`. thanks. too bad can't accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion in the comments:

*Are your region and locale set for the 4.3.2 & 4.3.3 devices? See if this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559182/how-do-you-interpret-dates-with-nsdateformatter/1559284#1559284) helps.*

Relevant code:

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone ran into this issue before. A workaround is written up here: [NSDateFormatter is returning null for date in ios 4.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386446/nsdateformatter-is-returning-null-for-date-in-ios-4-3-3)

Comment: Thanks, `substring` is another alternative. but i don't want do that here.